# React JS : How to check whether the user is using a browser url or desktop electron

Tags: reactjs

I have built a web-based application using React JS (CRA), but to access this application I created a portable desktop using Electron and Nativefier.

The question is how to create programming logic with React JS (JavaScript) so that it can detect whether the user is using a portable desktop or via a browser URL.

The goal is that users cannot use this application through the browser URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this from: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2288#issuecomment-337858978

You can check whether the user is currently using the electron app or the browser using this:

```js
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (userAgent.indexOf(' electron/') > -1) {
   // Electron-specific code
}
```

For your use-case you can probably include a check at your Root react component like this:

```
const App = () => {
   const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
   const isElectron = userAgent.indexOf(' electron/') > -1;

   if (!isElectron) {
       return <h1>Please use the electron app</h1>
   }

   // rest of the component code
}
```

Comment: Perfect !!!! I am build desktop app using Nativefier and add param --honest.
this function works well when tested using a browser or desktop app. Thank you very much